# Subtypes vs Derived Types in C++

Tags: c++, subtype, derived-types

I recently heard one of my coworkers claim that the concept of a "subtype" is not defined in C++.  He claims that "subtypes" are rightly called "derived types" in C++ terminology.  Is this true?  If I have:

`class A { };
class B : public A { };`

Can I call B a subtype of A? Or is it only valid to call B a "derived type" of A in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtype is not part of the common jargon in C++. The definition in Wikipedia (thanks Chad) is quite broad and in C++ could represent multiple different things, including but not limited to inheritance. For example, all iterator types from a given category and pointers could be *subtypes* of the iterator concept as they can be substituted in templates that require that concept (including the standard library algorithms).

I would use *derived* in general, other alternative words for the same (in different languages) could include *extends* (type A extends B) or *inherits*.

Answer (score 0):

A subtype is a specialized version of a type. In C++ a derived class is a subtype (subclass) of a base class type. A variable of the derived type could appear anywhere that a variable of the parent type is requested. A subtype of another type means you can use the subtype in all situations where the parent type could be used.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70hh8yzh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Derived types are new types that can be used in a program, and can
>   include directly derived types and composed derivative types.

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping):

> If S is a subtype of T, the subtyping relation is often written S <:
>   T, to mean that any term of type S can be safely used in a context
>   where a term of type T is expected.

This definition means that public inheritance fits for the following classes:

```
class T {};
class S : public T {};
```

However, C++ also provides `private` and `protected` inheritance, and these do not model the "is-a" relationship that `public` inheritance does, and therefore these types of inheritance do not meet the definition of subtype (as provided by wikipedia).

Subtype is not a common way in C++ to describe these relationships, even in the cases where the definition does appear to fit (`public` inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

Stroustrup seems to prefer "derived class" but will also call it a "subclass": see [this link](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astroustrup.com+subclass).

In http://www.stroustrup.com/hopl2.pdf he writes,

> The derived class concept is C++’s version of Simula’s prefixed class notion and thus a sibling of
>   Smalltalk’s subclass concept. The names derived class and base class were chosen because I
>   never could remember what was sub and what was super and observed that I was not the only one
>   with this particular problem.