# classes inherited in UVM

Tags: uvm

I am trying to learn UVM, and I just wanted to know that does this diagram below represent inheritence eg does uvm_object get inherited from uvm_void? I am reading the UVM 1.1 Class reference. It mentions on page 17 that

> The uvm_void class is the base class for all UVM classes. It is an
>   abstract class with no data members or functions. It allows for
>   generic containers of objects to be created, similar to a void pointer
>   in the C programming language. User classes derived directly from
>   uvm_void inherit none of the UVM functionality, but such classes may
>   be placed in uvm_void-typed containers along with other UVM objects.

If uvm_object is derived from uvm_void, then how does it have UVM functionality since classes derived from uvm_void shouldn't have any UVM functionality, but uvm_object has methods like clone, print, pack, unpack, record, compare etc.

When we write class uvm_* extends uvm_* eg. class uvm_component extends uvm_object, does it infer inheritence? Somewhere it also mentions the word subtype. Is subtype same as derived class?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 'derived class' is a form of 'subtype'. [Subtypes vs Derived Types in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13612238/1959732)

> If uvm_object is derived from uvm_void, then how does it have UVM functionality since classes derived from uvm_void shouldn't have any UVM functionality, but uvm_object has methods like clone, print, pack, unpack, record, compare etc.

This notion is incorrect, a derived class can implement new functionality. The restriction, objects cannot be created from abstract classes. A parent class handle can point to any object so long as it is a subtype. A handle can only access the methods and members of its own type, plus virtual methods that been override. Therefore if a handle is pointing to a subtype object, it cannot access the methods or members that were added by that subtype.

`uvm_void` is an empty abstract class. If you look into the UVM source code you will see it defiled as two lines:

```
virtual class uvm_void;
endclass
```

The purpose of `uvm_void` is to have a common parent type, so later on a generic container can be created that can hold any UVM related object. Such a container can even hold user-defined classes that inherit from `uvm_void` without relations to `uvm_object` (in practice this should not be done).

`uvm_object` implements the fundamental functionality used by UVM. The vast majority UVM classes inherit from `uvm_object` or one of its subtypes.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. UVM_VOID is the parent class of all UVM components and objects. It is just nothing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).